# В массив передать значения другого массива

Tags: c#, unity3d

нужно сделать так, по тригеру в значения массива sentences передавались значения массива из другого скрипта, и запускалась StartCoroutine.
как я только не пробовал значения не передает перед запуском. В чем тут проблема?

```
public class Dialog : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI textDisplay;
    public GameObject continueButton;
    public GameObject imagePhone;

    public string[] sentences;
    private int index;
    public float typingSpeed;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (textDisplay.text == sentences[index])
        {
            continueButton.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    public void StartCoroutine1() {
        StartCoroutine(TypeDialog());
        imagePhone.SetActive(true);
    } 

    IEnumerator TypeDialog()
    {
        foreach (char letter in sentences[index].ToCharArray())
        {
            textDisplay.text += letter;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(typingSpeed);
        }
    }
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////// Здесь тригер

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class Levl1_d1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    Dialog dialog;
    BaseDialog baseDialog;

    void Start()
    {
        baseDialog = GameObject.Find("BaseDialog").GetComponent<BaseDialog>();
        dialog = GameObject.Find("DialogManager").GetComponent<Dialog>();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
         dialog.sentences = baseDialog.levl1_d1;  
        dialog.StartCoroutine1();
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////  это база диалогов

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BaseDialog : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector]
    public string[] levl1_d1 = new string[] { "001", "002", "003" };
}
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что OnTriggerEnter2D в Levl1_d1 вызывается? Иными словами, объект Levl1_d1 точно входит в триггер? Если да, то проверьте, не лежит ли на сцене какой-то другой объект со  скриптом Dialog. Чтобы воспользоваться поиском "по скриптам" объектов сцены, введите "t: Dialog" в текстовом поле окна Hierarchy (скрин интерфейса: https://ibb.co/mq0pXzs)

Comment: OnTriggerEnter2D вызывается точно, когда coll.tag == "Player". 
я уже решил проблему, но вот только вопрос остается открытым, почему мне нужно инициализировать массив вот так:     [HideInInspector]
    public string[] levl1_d1;

    private void Start()
    {
        levl1_d1 = new string[] {
            "001 ",
            "002",
            "003" };
    }
а вот так он не инициализирует public class BaseDialog : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector]
    public string[] levl1_d1 = new string[] { "001", "002", "003" };
}

Comment: Во-первых, это совершенно другой вопрос.
Во-вторых, очень сложно читать код вот так, как вы написали.
В-третьих, я не вижу проблемы с заданием начального значения. Можно и так, и так инициализировать поле.

Comment: И да, коли нашли решение своей проблемы, будьте так любезны - опишите его здесь, прямо в ответе самому себе. Подумайте о будущих поколениях, которые, возможно, столкнутся с подобными трудностями и смогут отыскать решение здесь.

Comment: вопрос тот же. Почему значения из массива не передавались в другой массив. А дальше я уже понял что в исходном массиве была пустота из за того что он не был инициализирован(public string[] levl1_d1 = new string[] { "001", "002", "003" }; -- это не сработало)

Answer (score 2):

Это связано с реализацией в Unity класса `MonoBehaviour`. Экземпляр этого класса (а соответственно и наследников) создаётся в момент, когда вы вешаете класс на объект.

```
public class BaseDialog : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector]
    public string[] levl1_d1 = new string[] { "001", "002", "003" };
}
```

Подобный способ инициализации задаёт значение при создании нового экземпляра. Но! Он ничего не изменит в том классе, который был повешен на объект до появления этой строки.

Это связано с тем, что в Unity все `public` поля инициализируются в момент создания объекта. Любой `[SerializableField]` или `public` массив будет инициализирован новым пустым массивом при создании экземпляра класса (навешивании класса на GameObject), а значимые типы будут инициализированы `default` значениями.

Другими словами, если вы повесили класс на объект раньше, чем добавили код инициализации - массив уже будет инициализирован через `new string[0]`, после чего это будет сохранено, как состояние объекта.

В дальнейшем, после добавления строк - оно будет загружать поверх вашего кода состояние объекта, в котором указано, что массив на самом деле пустой.

Т.е. если вы сейчас на новый объект повесите скрипт с кодом выше - его массив будет правильно инициализирован.

Answer (score 0):

решением было инициализировать массив в void Start

```
[HideInInspector]
    public string[] levl1_d1;

    private void Start()
    {
        levl1_d1 = new string[] {
            "001 ",
            "002",
            "003" };
    }
```

не знаю с чем связано но так он не инициализировал

```
public class BaseDialog : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector]
    public string[] levl1_d1 = new string[] { "001", "002", "003" };
}
```